# Take html and remove the params from url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, trix

I am trying to make a helper method to parse a url that is generated by the trix rich text editor, which returns the private url to my aws, but needs to be public.

I have been trying to `split` and remove the pieces of the html that I don't need, but I just can't get the Ruby code right. [The gist](https://gist.github.com/cgibsonmm/d47449409b40e5867184e6932c3526be) shows the response and the method I have been trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove parts of the query params of all URLs within a string of html, right?

I would suggest that you first get rid of the special characters of the HTML. For example by using Nokogiri. Say we have the html in the `html_string`:

```
html_unescaped_string = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html_string).to_s
```

I am not sure what you want really to remove from the URLs. But let's assume you wanted to remove all query params from an URL, where the right side includes `'AWS'` (E.g. `what_ever=bla_AWS_bla`).

You could do that with a function like this:

```
sanitizer = Proc.new do |uri_string|
  URI.parse(uri_string).tap do |uri|
    new_params = CGI.parse(uri.query).transform_values do |values| 
      values.reject { |value| value.include?("AWS") }
    end
    new_params.reject! { |_k, v| !v.empty? }
    uri.query = new_params.empty? ? nil : URI.encode_www_form(new_params)
  end.to_s
end
```

For finding URLs in a string you can use the nice `URI.regexp`. With this you can do:

```
html_unescaped_string.gsub(URI.regexp, &sanitizer)
```

I hope that helps...